# "Apply" luminosity colors in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have some colourful objects:

[image: 1]

And plain colour background. When I applying Luminosity and transparency I have something like this:

[image: 2]

So my goal is "apply" these colours (and optionally transparency) to save it to SVG. When I trying to save one of these object as SVG it saves with original colours.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, blending modes are not supported in `.svg`. If they are, then the support is rudimentary.

What you want to do is select each of your objects with a blending mode and <kbd>Object</kbd> → <kbd>Flatten Transparency...</kbd>. Some expirmentation with the options might be needed if the basic settings don't yield what you want.

This revert the object back to the `normal` blending mode, and gives it the (almost) exact colour you saw it having with the blend mode.

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, would forego all transparency and simply recolor the object with varying shades of the blue.

I'm a firm believer that if it's a simple matter to *avoid transparency* settings during vector construction, you should do so. A 50% tint of the background blue would achieve nearly the exact same appearance and avoid *all* flattening issues.

Answer (score -1):

[Great lesson that explains what I need](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OHj7HHbslc).

[This YouTube video explains what transparency flattening is and how it affects objects by showing manual flattening rather than using an automated process.]

Comment: Hi Semyon, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!